# Why is jquery not working with wordpress enqueue?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I just switched the way I enqueue jquery in a theme from this method:

```
function my_init() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.7.2');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_init');
```

to this:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

function my_admin_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts_method');
```

The old version used 1.7.2, wordpress' built in version is 1.7.1.  I have tried just copy and pasting the address for the 1.7.1 into the first version and it breaks just the same.  The link is there in the source to the 1.7.1 version but jquery just does not work.  Any ideas what might cause this?

website url: www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/

Answer (score 0):

I don't what exactly problem is here, but try this.

```
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a plugin:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    // or
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

For more [info](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)...

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_scripts_method() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

function my_admin_scripts_method() {
// you don't need to load jquery here, because its automatically loaded in the adminby default 
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts_method');
```