# What else do I need to run jquery in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have been trying to get jquery to run in a wordpress theme that I'm building. I can get it to work if I use the traditional method for non-worpress sites:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I have read that this is not the correct way to use jquery in wordpress as it can cause conflicts and other problems. I've read the wordpress codex and this site: http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/ which was actually more helpful than the codex. I've checked into similar questions here on StackOverflow and tried the solutions listed there but jquery still won't load. Other sites I found about this topic were not very clear. Here is the code that I have so far in my functions.php file, but it's still not working:

```
function jqry_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}

add_action('init', 'jqry_init');
```

I've tried loading it from Google, directly from jquery, and referencing a copy of jquery that I have in a file on the site. Non of these work. I should mention that I'm doing all of this with xampp on localhost if that makes a difference. What am I missing?

**Update:**
Here are the snippets / other scripts I'm running:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/isotope.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            JQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var $container = $('#content');
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: '*',
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false,
                    }
                });

                JQuery('#nav a').click(function($) {
                    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                    $container.isotope({
                        filter: selector,
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 750,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            queue: false,
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Some of the other questions and solutions that I've tried:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944162/jquery-scripts-not-working-in-wordpress-tried-multiple-enqueue-methods
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342307/why-is-jquery-not-working-with-wordpress-enqueue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121550/enque-script-not-working-for-jquery-in-wordpress

Comment: When you say isn't working, is the script not being added to the page?  Do you have javascript errors?  Do you have a snippet of jquery that you are trying to run? If so please post your snippet and any errors.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. Jquery is not loading at all. It's not added to the page. In console: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Research for this topic on [wordpress.se], it's not advisable to deregister WP included jQuery, and, if done, some precautions must take place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook to add scripts.  You don't need the check for admin as there is another hook for admin scripts `admin_enqueue_scripts`

```
function jqry_init() {

    // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jqry_init');
```

If your jQuery snippet is still not working it may be due to a noconflict wrapper.

For example if the following isn't working and you are getting the `$ is not defined error`:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
   //do stuff here
});
```

You need to change that to

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    //do stuff here with the $ shorthand
});
```

**Update**

In your `header.php`
before the closing `</head>` tag please ensure you have 
`<?php wp_head();?>`

`wp_head()` is important because this is where functions added to `wp_enqueue_scripts` will be run.  Without it they won't be run.

Comment: @DigitalBrent did you also change the hook you were adding the script to? Should be `wp_enqueue_scripts` not `init`.  Added an update about having `wp_head()`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. I switched that in functions.php. Do I need to do anything special or make any changes in the head of the doc? Note: the entire head of the site is contained in my header.php file. Do I need to make any changes there?

Comment: Hey Jrod, I really appreciate you trying to help me. I've made all the changes that you've suggested but I'm still getting the same errors and JQuery doesn't appear to be loading at all. Here I have attached what I currently have from functions.php and header.php

header - http://jsfiddle.net/YpVUJ/2/
functions - http://jsfiddle.net/us8Xn/

Comment: Well thanks man. I finally got JQuery to load up, though the snippet is still not working. This is such a headache but thanks for your help.

Comment: `<?php wp_head();?>` needs to go before your JavaScript. That function prints out the enqueued scripts, but you are trying to use jQuery before it's loaded - http://jsfiddle.net/YpVUJ/3/

Comment: And technically you should be enqueuing `/scripts/isotope.js` with a dependency on `jquery` and including the other javascript in a file as well, then remove it from `header.php` - that way you can be sure all the required sources are loaded before your code.